# Ansible filter output start with specific letter

Tags: string, filter, ansible

I have a simple playbook and return available update package name as below. I would like to filter the output start with specific letter example to get package name start with 'n' letter. Any thoughts would be much appreciated :-)

```
---
- name: yum list updates
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: get updates list
    yum:
      list=updates
    register: yum

  - name: set fact
    set_fact:
      package_name: "{{ yum.results | map(attribute='name')| list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
package_name: "{{ yum.results|selectattr('name', 'search', '^n')|list }}"
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks, but not working. It prompted error:
"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{yum.results|selectattr('name', 'search', '^b')|list}}): expected string or buffer"}